# Json file not found after the Build

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'd like to find where the json file is saved. In the editor mode I can find it. However, when I make the build of the game, I cannot find it.

I'm using this script to save the game:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class DataManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameHandler data;
    private string file = "player.txt";

    public void Save()
    {
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
        WriteTopFile(file, json);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        data = new GameHandler();
        string json = ReadFromFile(file);
        JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, data);
    }

    private void WriteTopFile(string fileName, string json)
    {
        string path = GetFilePath(fileName);
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
        {
            writer.Write(json);
        } 
    }

    private string ReadFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        string path = GetFilePath(fileName);
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            print(path);
            using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return json;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("File not found");
            return "";
        }
    }

    private string GetFilePath(string fileName)
    {
        return Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + fileName;
    }
}
```

How can I find it guys? Can I specify its the path?

Comment: my gut tells me somewhere in C:\Users\USER\AppData.

Comment: But I'd like it in the build folder

Answer (score 1):

Files from `persistentDataPath` afaik will **not** be packed automatically into the built application.

**But** the `StreamingAssets` are.

> The built application can load the Asset at this address.

So what I usually do is using the [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html) while still being in the Editor. This is the same as simply putting a file into the folder `Assets/StreamingAssets`.

I prefer this I general since I don't want my development application bloating some files into any folder hidden on the Windows PC but instead within the according project's `Asset` folder.

Then on runtime after a build this folder is read-only and not visible/accessible on the device.

So I check if the according file exists in the `persistentDataPath`.

- If yes read I from there.
- If not then rather read it once from the `streamingAssetsPath` and copy it into the `persitentDataPath`.

---

Another important point:

**Do never use `+"/"+` for file paths**

rather use `Path.Combine` which uses automatically the correct platform specific path separator symbol!

---

The code depends a bit which is your target platform since the

> It is not possible to access the `StreamingAssets` folder on WebGL and Android platforms. No file access is available on WebGL. Android uses a compressed .apk file. These platforms return a URL. Use the `UnityWebRequest` class to access the Assets.

I will only add the code for standalone (UWP) because I have not much experience with Android but it should be the same just using a Coroutine and `UnityWebRequest` for reading the `streamingAssetsPath`

So in code it could be something like e.g.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

...

private string DataFolder
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    return Application.streamingAssetsPath;
#else
    return Application.persitentDataPath;
#endif
}

private string GetFilePath(string fileName)
{
    return Path.Combine(DataFolder, fileName);
}

//                  | Little typo here btw
//                  v
private void WriteTopFile(string fileName, string json)
{
    string filePath = GetFilePath(fileName);

    // Create folder if not exists
    if(!Directory.Exists(DataFolder)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(DataFolder);
    }

    using(var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
        {
            writer.Write(json);
        }
    } 

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    AssetDataBase.Refresh();
#endif
}
```

Now when reading as said before include a check if file exists I persistent path or not:

```
private string ReadFromFile(string fileName)
{
    var filePath = GetFilePath(fileName);
    var output = "";

    Debug.Log($"Trying to read file {filePath}");
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        Debug.Log($"File found! Reading from {filePath}");
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            output = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return output;
    }

    // Otherwise rather try to read from streaming assets
    var altFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, fileName);
    Debug.LogWarning($"File not found! Instead trying to read file {altFilePath}");

    if(File.Exists(altFilePath)
    {
        // read from here but directly also write it back to persistentDataPath
        Debug.Log($"File found. Reading from {altFilePath}");

        // As mentioned for Android you would now do the rest in a Coroutine 
        // using a UnityWebRequest.Get              

        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(altFilePath))
        {
            output = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // Now before returning also write it to persistentDataPath
        WriteTopFile(fileName, output);
        return output;
    }

    // If this also fails you didn't put such a file to `Assets/StreamingAssets` before the build
    Debug.LogError($"File also not found in {altFilePath}/n/nRemember to play it in 'Assets/StreamingAssets' before building!");
    return output;
}
```

---

*Note: Currently I'm only on the phone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear already :)*