# Don't Destroy on Load Object and GameData

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I want to save my game data as my 2D game progresses using a `DontDestroyOnLoad` object.

I have a `GameData` class/script which stores values like health, magicType, etc, a `SaveLoad` class/script which saves current values in the GameData class to Json and an empty game object called `PlayerData` that has both of the above scripts.

Currently, I'm saving values in one scene by using button click events. My object attached to the button is the `PlayerData` object, and I change values using the `GameData` script on the click event.

But this only works on the first scene - I can't attach the `PlayerData` object and store its `GameData` values because there is no PlayerData object in the editor.

So how can I attach this object, which is in a different scene? Or am I doing this wrong?

Here's a photo of my current project.
[image: my current project]

Also, when I save a boolean, then open my Json file, the file is empty. Is this normal? Here's my save and load code:

Load:

```
private string _filePath;
private static DataService _instance;

public DataService Instance
{
    get { return _instance; }
}

public GameData _gameData;

private void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}

public void LoadGameData()
{
    _filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "GameData1.json");
    string json;
    if (File.Exists(_filePath))
    {
        json = File.ReadAllText(_filePath);
        JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, _gameData);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("File missing.");
    }
}
```

Save:

```
public void SaveGameData1()
{
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(_gameData);
    _filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "GameData1.json");
    if (File.Exists(_filePath))
    {
        File.Create(_filePath).Dispose();
    }
    File.WriteAllText(_filePath,json);
}
```

EDIT: This is the code of my GameData class:

```
[Serializable]
    public class GameData : MonoBehavior
    {
        public float Health { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: As per [tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), no tags in question titles, please.

Comment: I would recommend using player prefs over json files to save your data in Unity. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: I've read online that playerprefs isn't very safe, and that Json is the way to go...

Comment: @Brandon PlayerPrefs is made for saving user preferences like music volume, not for storing game progress since it is reset everytime the app gets updated and also visible and editable for users. Json is a good little step but you should additionally use some encryption anyway ;)

Comment: Could you add the code of `GameData`? Are you sure both scripts need to be a `MonoBehaviour`?

Comment: @derHugo PlayerPrefs remain on app update. Only if user deletes the app and then reinstalls then they get wiped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Data Path

First of all as just recently answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58782204/7111561) I wouldn't use the `persistentDataPath` for development but rather the `streamingAssetsPath` and on first app run copy the file over.

---

#### Singleton Pattern

I see you have the first half of a Singleton pattern **but**: You never assigned a value to `instance`. I usually would do it "lazy" in the property or `Awake` like e.g.

```
private static DataService instance;
public static DataService Instance
{
    if(instance) return instance;

    instance = FindObjectOfType<DataService>();

    if(instance) return instance;

    // If it wasnt found in the scene create it now
    instance = new GameObject("DataService", typeof (GameData)). AddComponent<DataService>();
    instance._gameData = instance.GetComponent<GameData>();

    DontDestroyOnLoad (instance.gameObject);

    return instance;
}

private void Awake ()
{
    if(instance && instance != this)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Another instance of DataService I already in use");
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }

    if(instance) return;

    instance = this;

    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);

    if(!_gameData) _gameData = GetComponent<GameData>();
}
```

---

#### Or static Class

Actually with the code you provided I doubt that any of your two classes really needs to be a `MonoBehaviour`!

You could probably simply use something like

```
public static class DataService
{
    private const string FILE_NAME = "GameData1.json";

    public static GameData GameData = new GameData();

    public static void SaveGameData1()
    {
        var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(_gameData);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, FILE_NAME);

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Create(filePath);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(filePath,json);
    }

    public static void LoadGameData()
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, FILE_NAME);
        
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            var json = File.ReadAllText(_filePath);
            JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, GameData);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("File missing.");
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
[Serializable]
public class GameData
{
    public float SomeValue;

    ...
}
```

Now you can from everywhere simply call

```
DataService.LoadGameData();
```

And then access value like

```
DataService.GameData.SomeValue = ...;
```

---

#### For the buttons

I would create a class `DataServiceButton` which is attached to a UI.Button and registers itself as a listener to `onClick` like

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(UI.Button))]
public class DataServiceButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum ButtonType
    {
        Save,
        Load
    }

    // This is set via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private ButtonType type;

    // Here you can already reference the according Button component
    [SerializeField] private Button button;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!button) button = GetComponent<Button>();

        // Register as callback
        button.onClick.AddListener(HandleClick);
    }

    private void HandleClick()
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case ButtonType.Load:
                DataService.LoadGameData();
                // OR IF YOU STICK TO THE SINGLETON
                //DataService.Instance.LoadGameData();
                break;
            case ButtonType.Save:
                DataService.SaveGameData();
                // OR ACCORDINGLY WITH SINGLETON
                //DataService.Instance.SaveGameData();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

The question why your file is empty after writing data unfortunately can not be answered without seeing the code of your `GameData` class...

Make sure your types are serializeable.

Comment: Thank you! If I remove MonoBehavior from my GameData class, is FromJsonOverwrite still acceptable? or I do I need to change my code?

Comment: You should remove the `{get;set;}` and rather use fields instead of properties