# how to Load json for windows build unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

I have tried alot of solution but no one is working in my case, my question is simple but i cant find any answer specially for windows build. I have tried to load json form persistent , streaming and resource all are working good in android but no any solution work for windows build. here is my code please help me.

```
public GameData gameData;
    private void LoadGameData()
    {
        string path = "ItemsData";
        TextAsset targetFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);
        string json = targetFile.text;
        gameData = ResourceHelper.DecodeObject<GameData>(json);
        //  gameData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData>(json);
        print(gameData.Items.Count);
}
```

here is my data class

```
[Serializable]
public class GameData
{
    [SerializeField]
    public List<Item> Items;


    public GameData()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Id;
    public string[] TexturesArray;

    public bool Active;

    public Item()
    {
    }
    public Item(string _id, string[] _textureArray ,  bool _active = true)
    {
        Id = _id;
        TexturesArray = _textureArray;
        Active = _active;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: what about [`JsonUtility.FromJson`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html)? Note `Item` should be [`[Serializable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute)!

Comment: Use either the builtin JsonUtility of unity, or use json.net (it's on the asset store). Both are pretty great, the later allowing for more advanced things

Comment: can you share a piece of your json?

Comment: You can use GameData data = JObject.Parse(StringJson).ToObject<GameData>();

Comment: no, error.. plz help

Comment: here is my json

Comment: {
  "Items": [
    {
      "Id": "Cube",
      "TexturesArray": ["T1" , "T2" , "T3"],
    "Active": true
    },
 {
      "Id": "Ground",
      "TexturesArray": ["Tile_Mexican_basecolor" , "11_16_1_d" , "Ground_Rain_basecolor"],
    "Active": true
    },
 
 {
      "Id": "Frame",
      "TexturesArray": ["Picture7" , "Picture1" , "Picture17"],
    "Active": true
    }
  ]
}

Comment: gameData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData>(json);

this is not working , gameData.Items.Count contains 0 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be (de)serialized `Item` should be [`[Serializable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute)

```
using System;

...

[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    ...
}
```

Then you could simply use Unity's built-in [`JsonUtility.FromJson`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html):

```
public GameData gameData;
private void LoadGameData()
{
    string path = "ItemsData";
    TextAsset targetFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);
    string json = targetFile.text;
    gameData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData>(json);
    print(gameData.Items.Count);
}
```

---

For loading something from e.g. `persistentDataPath` I always use something like

```
var path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "FileName.txt")
using (var fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        var json = sr.ReadToEnd();

        ...
    }
}
```

For development I actually place my file into `StreamingAssets` (`streamingAssetsPath`) while running the code in the Unity Editor.

Then on runtime I read from `persistentFilePath`. If the file is not there I first copy it from the `streamingassetsPath` the first time.

[Here I wrote more about this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58782204/7111561)